# javascript promise chain with fetch not in sequence

Tags: javascript, promise, sequence, fetch-api, chain

I want to dynamically build a promise chain, that should do things in the background. Mainly it should do some output on the web page.

That works until I put promises from `fetch` into the chain. Those promises are not executed in the expected sequence.

The following example shows how the chain is build:

```
var chain = Promise.resolve();
for(var i = 0; i < actions.length; ++i)
  chain = actions[i].extendChain(chain);

function actionExample(chain) {
  return chain.then(...);
}
```

That works with direct output:

```
function actionOutput(chain) {
  return chain.then(new Promise(resolve => {
    print('text');
    resolve();
  }));
}
```

But fetch or is not in sequence:

```
function actionLoad(chain) {
  const url = '...';
  return chain.then(new Promise(() => print('run action load\n')))
    .then(() => fetch(url))
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(processResponse)
    .then(requestOutput)
    .then(receiveOutput);
}
```

The function `requestOutput` also contains a fetch, but already the call of `processResponse` is delayed.

What can I change so that all steps are executed in the wanted sequence?

Comment: The way you're using promises in `actionOutput` is incorrect. The `.then()` method accepts a function, not a `Promise` instance

Comment: Why are you creating a promise that never resolved in the then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason to create new promises here. Passing a `Promise` instance to `.then()` is also incorrect as it requires one or two functions.

The `.then()` method **always** returns a new promise that resolves with the return value of the function provided

```js
function actionOutput(chain) {
  return chain.then(() => print('text'));
}


function actionLoad(chain) {
  const url = '...';
  return chain
    .then(() => print('run action load\n')) // resolves with return value of
                                            // `print()`, probably `undefined`
    .then(() => fetch(url))
    .then((response) => response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(res))
    .then(processResponse)
    .then(requestOutput)
    .then(receiveOutput);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and simple answer. That helps!